# How to identify which type of authentication is supported in jira

Tags: jira, python-jira

I am running below command
curl.exe -D- -X GET -H "Authorization: Basic c3VzaW5naDpZZ3ZxYXozMjEj" -H "Content-Type: application/json" "https://product-ira.ciena.com/rest/api/2/issue/QA-31"

Server output
curl.exe -D- -X GET -H "Authorization: Basic c3VzaW5naDpZZ3ZxYXozMjEj" -H "Conten
t-Type: application/json" "https://product-jira.ciena.com/rest/api/2/issue/QA-31"
HTTP/2.0 401
server:nginx
date:Sat, 23 Apr 2016 08:51:43 GMT
content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8
content-length:4304
x-arequestid:291x14654489x2
x-seraph-loginreason:AUTHENTICATED_FAILED
www-authenticate:OAuth realm="https%3A%2F%2Fproduct-jira.ciena.com"
x-content-type-options:nosniff
set-cookie:JSESSIONID=4B0B091270F3D780C8A3D547B8DB9E1C; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly

Unauthorized (401)

###################################################

Does it means my company JIRA server support oAuth type authentication only

Comment: I am getting this issue .https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-34657  . My server version is 6.3.15

Comment: [Check this post on Atlassian Answers](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/161692/check-if-http-basic-authentication-is-enabled) and see if the curl command `curl -v http://jira-urll?os_authType=basic` returns `WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="protected-area"`. Also, see if you have Seraph Authenticator installed, like it says.